# JQuery Progress bar implementation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found this Jquery progress bar function and I want to simply use it to show the progress bar while my web page is loading. Since my page is loading a bit slow, it serves as a reminder to the user that the page hasn't stopped loading. Below is the javascript and css part. Now how to implement it in the html part? What do I inlcude in the html body?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.progressbar.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var progress_key = '<?= $uuid ?>';

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#pb1").progressBar();
            $("#pb2").progressBar({ barImage:  
           'images/progressbg_yellow.gif'} );
            $("#pb3").progressBar({ barImage: 
           'images/progressbg_orange.gif', showText: false} );
            $("#pb4").progressBar(65, { showText: false, barImage: 
           'images/progressbg_red.gif'} );
            $(".pb5").progressBar({ max: '2000', textFormat: 
             'fraction', callback: function(data) { if (data.running_value == 
               data.value) { 
            alert("Callback example: Target reached!"); } }} );
            $("#uploadprogressbar").progressBar();
        });

</script>
<style type="text/css">
        table tr { vertical-align: top; }
        table td { padding: 3px; }
        div.contentblock { padding-bottom: 25px; }  
        #uploadprogressbar { display: none; }
</style>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Based on the demo you are referencing you need

```
<span class="progressBar" id="pb1"></span>
```

with either id pb1 .. pb4

http://jsfiddle.net/RUBSx/1/

Comment: Thanks. But it loads along with all the other elements in my web page. I want it to load first, before everything else loads..

Comment: You don't just plug it in and it works magically.  This plugin needs to be told how to update its current progress.  What you are asking depends on what(content)\how you are loading the page.